# Store all received values in a different string with threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I got this code, and I'm trying to separate all the emails, passwords and the third line in a different string. Here is the code:

```
import random
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

FILENAME = 'testing/pokens.txt'
NTHREADS = 5

def myfunc():
    with open(FILENAME) as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
        line = random.choice(lines).strip()
        tokens = line.split(':')
        return ' '.join(tokens)

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        printable = set()
        for _ in range(NTHREADS):
            future = executor.submit(myfunc)
            futures.append(future)
        for future in futures:
            printable.add(future.result())
        for p in printable:
            print(p)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So for example "p" prints out `j3mxshasn12312zh@oncemail.co.kr 75d9d216fba123216-4e*%& third_line` with removing duplicate line threads. I want all the emails, all the passwords and all the third lines stored in a different string (email1,email2,pass1,pass2,third_line1,third_line2, etc).

`Pokens.txt` file sample:

```
1thtx3213wqpzxn@oncemail.co.kr:2664a171322139489348:third_line
2bixr3123dxpdzz@oncemail.co.kr:b1*+b0ab9b(17213213^9$#@d1e:third_line
j3mxshasn12312zh@oncemail.co.kr:75d9d216fba123216-4e*%&:third_line
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: I don't know how to put them into a string and use them in another function

Comment: So your question isn't really about multithreading at all, it's about combining the results the way you want — correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Comment: OK, please be clearer about the format of the output string (or strings?).

Comment: For example, for each email there will be a different string like email1 = '' email2 = '' and for passwords, thirdlines the same

Comment: Oh, I see. Dynamically creating variables is not considered a good way to do things — any is usually unnecessary anyway.

Comment: But how do i get these emails and passwords separately then?

Comment: You should append all the email addresses to a list named `emails`, each password to one named `passwords`, etc. and reference them by index.